# DatePicker using React Hook Form not displaying format correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, datepicker

I'm using DatePicker in side a react hook form.

I'm able to get my form to display the Date I pick but it's not in the format I'm expecting.

The text box the is correct `August 19`, but when I try to get it to display using
it comes back at as this format 2022-09-19T23:51:47.000Z

[image: Timestamp]

I'm not sure what I'm missing as i'm pretty stump at the moment on what needs for it to display correctly.

```
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
              <Controller
                name="Date"
                control={control}
                defaultValue=""
                rules={{
                  required: { value: true, message: "Date is required" },
                }}
                render={({ field }) => (
                  <DatePicker
                    openTo="month"
                    views={["month", "day"]}
                    label="month and date"
                    value={field.value}
                    onChange={(e, data) => 
                      field.onChange(data);
                    }
                    inputFormat="MMMM dd"
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField {...params} helperText={null} />
                    )}
                    {...field}
                  />
                )}
              />
            </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `date-fns` you can do this with the `ISOString`:

```js
format(new Date('2022-09-19T23:51:47.000Z'), 'MMMM DD', { locale: 'US' });
```

It would return:
`September 19`